# LibGDX - i need an event like mouseMoved but it shouldn't care about which buttons are pressed

Tags: java, libgdx, input

Using ClickListener I have events like enter(), exit(), and mouseMoved(). But when I have any mouse buttons pressed, moveMoved() won't fire because that's how it works. There is touchDragged() but this will only fire if touchDown happened on Actor (or Actor's tap square). I'd like an event that would fire even if any mouse buttons was pressed outside Actor and his tap square, and keep firing each time mouse is moved over the Actor. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should implement your own InputProcessor. Here is article on libgdx wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling

Comment: I'm using ClickListener which extends InputProcessor. But it doesn't have event handling methods that I need. It does have though isOver() method and Actors have hit(), but when should I call it to check if mouse is over any of Actors? Every frame in some actor's act() method? That's not how input event handling should be done, right?

Comment: I asume that you're using Scene2D. Create your own InputProcessor, e.g. `MyInput implements InputProcessor`. Perhaps you will copy some method from ClickListener. Give MyInput reference to stage or scene and create method in stage which will update last result from isOver actor. Run this method in mouseMoved in MyInput. For mouse buttons clicked do something similar in keyDown/keyUp. If you also want something to render you should also add fuction in render method in your stage class. And finally remember to setup inputprocessor for stage with `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(myInput);`